# how to connect to secure cassandra from wso2bam

Tags: security, cassandra, wso2

In our setup, we have WSO2 BAM connecting an external Datastax Cassandra cluster. here the WSO2 BAM is acting as Data Recvr and dumping data in external cassandra cluster.

We wanted to know if we secure the DSE cassandra cluster with username/password security.. how can we specify the authentication details in WSO2 BAM for connecting securely to DSE cluster.

I read about cassandra-auth.xml in 
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/SS103/Changing+the+Default+Cassandra+Configuration

but seems like cassandra-auth.xml is more for authenticating into -management console UI

Please advice
Thanks
Rajiv Patil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around that is working for us -

We created the same user as the default WSO2 admin user (admin/admin) on the Cassandra. With this the WSO2 BAM is able to successfully connect to a secured Cassandra (External). Looks like by default WSO2 BAM is using the current admin user credentials for connecting to Cassandra as well.

Probably there should be an option in Cassandra-Component.xml to specify the username/password apart from the Cassandra Nodes in the cluster.

Comment: UPDATE- While we were able to insert data into secured Datastax Cassandra with the above changes. However the Analytic part continues to fail i.e. running Hive Script against secured DSE fails we passed the credentials via Cassandra datasource.. while the Hive table definition part works but the map/reduce jobs fail with "You are not logged in.." kind of errors

Answer (score 1):

You can provide username/password for cassandra datasource in configuration file found in `BAM_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml`

**EDIT-**

Here's a sample configuration which is the default

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE</name>
        <description>The datasource used for Cassandra data</description>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/EVENT_KS</url>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
</datasource>
```

Comment: Thanks. If possible can you please provide a sample config for Cassandra Data Source, as the default master-datasources.xml comes with RDBMS data sources.

Comment: Also Nufail.. I am not looking for specifying the cassandra credentials while doing the Hive Script... but while storing the data.. in that also we need to use master-datasources.xml ?

Comment: Check my edit. It is the default config in master-datasources. When you change `master-datasources.xml` you need to restart the server. Then it will use the provided credentials whenever it accesses cassandra.

Comment: Thanks. But this didnt work-out. We are on WSO2 BAM 2.2.0 .. your solution will work on this version ? I had doubts with regards to version since I didnt find the default WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DATASOURCE in my master-datasources.xml..

Comment: Rajiv, in BAM versions prior to 2.3.0, Cassandra server credentials are specified in each hive script rather than in a centralised location (i.e. `master-datasources.xml`). So the Hive scripts also need to be updated with the server credentials for them to work properly. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 BAM,

For data insertion , cassandra authentication credentials will be given trough data agent (publisher) configuration. Which are server credentials. And those credentials will be used for server authentication as well as cassandra authentication. So basically particular tanent credentials will be used to authenticate Cassandra too.

And credentials in master-datasources.xml will only be used to retrieve data from cassandra for analytics.